# Ran cell "plot_flight_path(64, 16, 0)" but it did not show up on Sagemath.com

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am fairly new to Python, and am trying to learn the numerical methods concepts before understanding the program.

There is a .py file written for a function called phugoid.py, but I cannot seem to get the graph to show on ipython editor Sagemath. (Sagemath has matplotlib).

```
In [9]: %run phugoid.py
        %matplotlib inline

In [1]: plot_flight_path(64, 16, 0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e57d3fb06a4a> in <module>()
      1 #zt = 64, z = 16, theta = 0
----> 2 plot_flight_path(64, 16, 0)

NameError: name 'plot_flight_path' is not defined
```

Here is the github file of my project (it's only two files, the function and the notebook).

[Sagemath Project Link](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/89cb6371-02fa-4e95-a21d-fbf17ad4ae76/files/)

[Github Project Link](https://github.com/trooper5010/Module-1-Lesson-1)

Please explain what I am doing wrong for a 5 year old.... thanks.